# AndEngine - TimerHandler not providing contact between bodies

Tags: android, andengine

Im making a jumper game. The objetive is stay alive jumping platforms.
I start the game with my character and 3 platforms. The next platforms I generate randomly with a timerhandler.
Its almost ready but Im facing some problems with a timerhandler.
Im using it to spawn platforms (static bodys) once every second.

```
private void addPlat(int x, int y) 
{
    platform = new Platform(x, y, vbom, physicsWorld);
    attachChild(platform);      
}

private void createPlatSpawn() 
{
    float mEffectSpawnDelay = 1f;

    platSpawnTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay, true, new ITimerCallback() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {                  

                platformList.add(platform);

                if (platformList.getLast().getY() >= 240 && platformList.getLast().getY() < 400) 
                {
                    yCoord = (int) (platform.getY() - addNumber.nextInt(160));
                }
                else if (platformList.getLast().getY() < 240 && platformList.getLast().getY() >= 50)
                {
                    yCoord = (int) (platform.getY() + addNumber.nextInt(160));
                }
                xCoord = (int) (platform.getX() + 200);

                addPlat(xCoord, yCoord);
        }
    });

    resourcesManager.engine.registerUpdateHandler(platSpawnTimerHandler);

}
```

To jump I use a variable footContacts, when its positive it can jump, otherwise it cant

Here the contact listener

```
private ContactListener contactListener()
{
    ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
    {
        public void beginContact(Contact contact)
        {
            final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

            if (x1.getBody().getUserData() != null && x2.getBody().getUserData() != null)
            {
                if (x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player"))
                {
                    player.increaseFootContacts();
                }
            }
        }

        public void endContact(Contact contact)
        {
            final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

            if (x1.getBody().getUserData() != null && x2.getBody().getUserData() != null)
            {
                if (x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player"))
                {
                    player.decreaseFootContacts();
                }
            }
        }

        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
        {

        }

        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse)
        {

        }
    };
    return contactListener;
}
```

Here is the method inside the class Player, to make him jump

```
public void jump()
{
    if (footContacts < 1) 
    {
        return; 
    }
    body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(body.getLinearVelocity().x, 15)); 
}
```

The first 3 platforms the jump action works perfectly but when he interact with the platforms created by the timerhandler, it doesnt work. Anyone can help me?

Adding the method to create the first 3 platforms:

```
private void createFirstPlat() 
{
    addPlat(200, 200);
    addPlat(400, 300);
    addPlat(600, 150);
}
```

Class Platform

```
public class Platform extends Sprite{

private Body body;

public Platform(float pX, float pY, VertexBufferObjectManager vbo, PhysicsWorld physicsWorld) 
{   
    super(pX, pY, ResourcesManager.getInstance().platform_region, vbo);
    createPhysics(physicsWorld);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private void createPhysics (PhysicsWorld physicsWorld)
{

    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, this, BodyType.StaticBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0.5f));

    body.setUserData("platform");

    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, body, true, false)
    {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
        {
            super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have post more code where you manually crate those 3 working platforms. It's possible that the problem is in .setUserData which I can't see because you haven't posted your Platform class as well.

Another possible problem is that you don't attach it to right entity or there is a problem with physiscsConnector which you maybe don't initialize. Try to create

```
public Entity foregroundLayer = new Entity();
```

and attach it to the scene. Then in addPlat use

```
foregroundLayer.attachChild(platform)
```

If that won't help please paste your Platform class and how you create them for first three times.

PS By the way, it's great solution when you want to control layers. For example you want some sprites to be on top and some sprites to be on background while overlapping. The important thing is attaching order so you first attach backgroundLayer and then foregroundLayer. Finally you can attach other entites for those two layers at any time and it will be shown as you expect.

Comment: I'm new to AndEngine and to android. I followed a tutorial on http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html and now I'm trying to create a game. I created the layer that you mentioned and added the code that you asked but I'm having a NullPointerException error. I declared the layer on the top of the code public Entity foregroundLayer = new Entity(); then, I attached it on the createScene method attachChild(foregroundLayer); then I used it to attach the character and the platforms

Comment: you have to create the layer inside createScene method too. just initialize it globaly by: Entity foregroundLayer; and then in createScene: foregroundLayer = new Entity();

Comment: Ok, no errors now but when the character comes in contact with the fourth platform (created by the timerhandler), I believe that the footContacts doesn't increment and then the jump action can't happen.
I'm having some trouble on debbuging it, could you have patience and explain me how could i debbug it? I can also send you the apk file, so you can see the problem happening

Comment: You can implement it by adding boolean flag to player. If he collides with the platform you do player.setJumping(false). In method when you jump you should check if the flag is set or not. If player is jumping you shouldn't allow to jump again. http://wklej.org/id/1341786/ and http://wklej.org/id/1341788/ This is how I do it

Comment: Hey man.. I apologize for my stupid topic, I found my error.
It was on the condition if (x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")
In the first 3 platforms "x2" was the player but in those created by the timerhandler "x1" was the player
corrected it by changing the condition to if (x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player") || x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("player"))  Thanks for your attention.